# SSL error for external API calls with the tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat

Something was changed in network configuration at my company to remediate log4j vulnerability but now my API calls are failing saying: SSL certificate chain is invalid .

I have tried setting cacert in jvm with the certificate from chrome but it does not work. Any suggestion on where to get the correct certificate from? and jvm cacert is the right place to update it?

Comment: What is failing? Inbound (to you tomcat) calls or outbound (from your tomcat app to another app) calls? It sounds like outbounds calls are failing in which case the server/api you are calling has the certificate you need to fetch and install on the local tomcat/server (assuming you trust it).

Comment: It is for outbound on the tomcat installed on the CentOS 6. The issue did fix after adding correct certificate in jvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the cacert in JVM with proper certificate, will resolve the ssl certificate issue. But make sure you use correct certificate to complete certificate chain.
Reference document - https://www.grim.se/guide/jre-cert